# Django extend template

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views

I still very new to Django.

I have 4 .html files: header.html(generic header for every page), body.html(load necessary css file and generate navigation button according to user roles), home.html and apply.html

Here is what I want to do:
1)header.html(generic title for every page) parent of body.html.
2)body.html parent of home.html and apply.html

here is my code in header.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static "favicon.ico" %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'loginTemplate.css' %}" />
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

Here is my code in body.html:

```
{% extends "header.html" %}
{% block body %}
{% for role in roles %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bodyTemplate.css' %}"/>
</head>
<body>
 <div><!--place my button here</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my code in home.html and apply.html:

```
{% extends "body.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div>load user detail<div>
{% endblock %}
```

Question: When i login to my test user, home.html showed the interface design that I want because bodyTemplate.css is included. But when I press a button that will link to apply.html, it showed me a white page with empty styling words and no button.

Comment: Does your "apply" view set any roles?

Comment: Nope. I realized that after you mention about it. Then i do some code checkup and that is one reason why the page didnt show any buttons like home.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't directly answer your question, but that's not the best way to use template inheritance. What you want is one base template with **all** the basic html layout, ie :

```
# base.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static "favicon.ico" %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'loginTemplate.css' %}" />
    {% block extra-head %}
    {# you can add any page-specific additional headers here #}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{# now you can have various "layout" subtemplates hooking into 'body' #}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Also note that in your code you have this:

```
{% block body %}
{% for role in roles %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bodyTemplate.css' %}"/>
  </head>

 <body>
   <div><!--place my button here</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Which will actually close the `head` tag and open the `body` tag as many time as you have items in `roles`...  Which can be either zero (if "roles" is empty or not defined in the current context) meaning you won't have the  bodyTemplate.css and invalid html doc (unclosed head, no body), or more than once which means you will have as many links to the same css, and still an invalid html doc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It actually did help even it not in a very directly way. Now I can see where are my mistakes. Yup I do agree is not best way to use template inheritance. Reason of doing that is that I use header.html for my login page as well so I don't need to create extra template for 1 page. Other than login page, page like home.html will need buttons for user. And thanks for pointing out my amateur coding too. With that, i found out why apply.html doesnt print out the button because my roles is empty. That's will always remind me during other page development.

Comment: Is saving one extra template really worth the pain of having to maintain a weird and brittle template layout ??? Well, not my problem but...

Comment: Haha, not really I mean I dont mind to have extra 1 template. But this is what i get when i get the code. So .... I just change all those "weird template" to a normal template that it should be ...